# Converting an RGB image to a YCbCr color space image

Tags: android, image, opencv, image-processing

Can anyone help me to convert an RGB colour space image to YCbCr colour space image using opencv Android?

Comment: Did you search this site?  What language are you using?

Comment: yup i had searched for it but didn't get anything meaningful. i am using java language.

Comment: i have converted the image from the drawable to YCrCb color space. but actually i want to convert the captured image to YCrCb color space.

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.android);
        Mat source = new Mat();
        Mat dest = new Mat();
        Utils. bitmapToMat( img, source);

        Imgproc. cvtColor(source, dest, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb);
    

        Bitmap btmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(dest.width(),dest.height(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils. matToBitmap(dest,btmp);
        imageView1. setImageBitmap (btmp);
    }

Comment: How can i use this for run time(captured image by camera). I am totally new with android.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example of how to convert an RGB image to the HSV color space [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_dip/color_space_conversion.htm). 
 Using that code and changing the color space field conversion value to COLOR_RGB2YCrCb:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;

import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class Main {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {

      try {
         System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
         File input = new File("digital_image_processing.jpg");
         BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input); 
         byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
         Mat mat = new Mat(image.getHeight(),image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
         mat.put(0, 0, data);

         Mat mat1 = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
         Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb)//original Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

         byte[] data1 = new byte[mat1.rows()*mat1.cols()*(int)(mat1.elemSize())];
         mat1.get(0, 0, data1);
         BufferedImage image1 = new BufferedImage(mat1.cols(), mat1.rows(), 5);
         image1.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, mat1.cols(), mat1.rows(), data1);

         File ouptut = new File("hsv.jpg");
         ImageIO.write(image1, "jpg", ouptut);

      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}
```